# sas, combine, unknown code datasets observations

Tags: sas, dataset

I need help reading the code below. I am not sure what specific parts in this code are doing. For example, what does `( firstobs = 2 keep = column3 rename = (column3 = column4) )` do?

Also, what does `( obs = 1 drop = _all_ );` do?

I have also not used `column5 = ifn( first.column1, (.), lag(column3) );` before. What does this do?

I am reading someone else's code. I wish I could provide more detail. If I find a solution, I will post it. Thanks for your help.

```
data out.dataset1;
set out.dataset2;
by column1;
WHERE column2 = 'N';
set out.dataset1 ( firstobs = 2 keep = column3 rename = (column3 = column4) )
    out.dataset1 ( obs = 1 drop = _all_ );
FORMAT column5 DATETIME20.;
FORMAT column4 DATETIME20.;
column5 = ifn( first.column1, (.), lag(column3) );
column4 = ifn(  last.column1, (.), column4 );
IF first.column1 then DIF=intck('dtday',column4,column3);
ELSE DIF= intck('dtday',column5,column3); 
format column6 $6.; 
IF first.column1
OR intck('dtday',column5,column3) GT 20 THEN column6= 'HARM';
ELSE column6= 'REPEAT'; 
run;
```

Comment: The input dataset name on your first SET statement does not match the name used  (twice) in the second SET statement.  Not referencing the same data will make this data step not work right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you need to learn about SAS datastep languange!
This series of things happening in the parenthesis are datastep options
You can use those options when ever you are referencing a table, even in a proc sql
The options you have:
 [firstobs](https://v8doc.sas.com/sashtml/lgref/z0131129.htm) : This starts the datafeed on the record enter in your case 2 it means SAS will start on the table on the 2nd record.

[keep](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/ledsoptsref/63326/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p0vw9lyyxk1cxkn0zzfemrsr3t9a.htm) : This will only use the fields in list rather than using all the field in the table 
[rename](https://v8doc.sas.com/sashtml/lgref/z0203026.htm) = rename will rename field, so it works like an alias in SQL

[OBS](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/ledsoptsref/63326/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p0h5nwbig8mobbn1u0dwtdo0c0a0.htm) = will limit the amount of record you pull out of a table like top or limit in SQL

[DROP](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000202902.htm) = would remove the fields selected from the table in your case *all* is used wich means he's dropping all the fields.

as for the functions:

[LAG](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000212547.htm)  is keeping the value from the previous record for the field you put in parenthesis so DPD_CLOSE_OF_BUSINESS_DT

[INF](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a002604573.htm) = Works like a case or if. Basically you create a condition in the 1st argument and then the 2nd argument is applied when your condition in the 1st argument is true, the 3rd argument get done in the event that your condition on the 1st argument is false.

So to answer that question if it's the first record for the variable  SOR_LEASE_NBR then the field Prev_COB_DT  will be . otherwise it will be a previous value of DPD_CLOSE_OF_BUSINESS_DT.

The best advise I can give you is to start googling SAS and the function name you are wondering what it does, then it's a matter of encapsulation!

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Basically your data step is using the LAG() function to look back one observation and the extra SET statement to look ahead one observation.

The IFN() function calls are then being used to make sure that missing values are assigned when at the boundary of a group.

You then use these calculated PREV and NEXT dates to calculate the DIF variable.

Note for this to work you need to be referencing the same input dataset in the two different SET statements (the dataset used in the last with the `obs=1` and `drop=_all_` dataset options 
doesn't really need to be the same since it is not reading any of the actual data, it just has to have at least one observation).

Answer (score 0):

> ( firstobs = 2 keep = DPD_CLOSE_OF_BUSINESS_DT rename =
>   (DPD_CLOSE_OF_BUSINESS_DT = Next_COB_DT) ) do?

Here the code firstobs=2 says SAS to read the data from 2nd observation in the dataset.
and also by using rename option trying to change the name of the variable.

> (obs = 1 drop = _all_);

obs=1 is reading only the 1st obs in the dataset. If you specify obs=2 then up to 2nd obs will be read.

drop = _all_ , is dropping all of your variables.

Firstobs:
Can read part of the data. If you specify Firstobs= 10, it starts reading the data from 10th observation.

Obs :
If specify obs=15, up to 15th obs the data will be readed.

If you run the below table, it gives you 3 observations ( from 2nd to 4th ) in the output result.

Example;

```
DATA INSURANCE;
INFILE CARDS FIRSTOBS=2 OBS=4;
INPUT NAME$ GENDER$ AGE INSURANCE $;
CARDS;
SOWMYA  FEMALE  20  MEDICAL
SUNDAR  MALE    25  MEDICAL
DIANA   FEMALE  67  MEDICARE
NINA    FEMALE  56  MEDICAL
RUN;
```

Comment: Note that your example is using the options on an INFILE statement instead of the dataset options that were used in the original program. Fortunately those particular options are available on both with similar meanings.